# Notice: Undefined property: nusoapclient::$operation in /PATH/nusoap.php on line 6837

Tags: php, nusoap

I got the following error in my nusoap file,

```
Notice: Undefined property: nusoapclient::$operation in /PATH/nusoap.php on line 6837
```

Any one got this error and have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I got the correct solution after upgrade the soap version. now the problem is sort over and working well. I did't get the problem again.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I was using the "send" method instead of call. It looks like operation gets set when "call" is called, but is not set when send is called by itself.

did this:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($url);
$client->operation = "SomeOperation";
$client->send($data,$url."/SomeOperation");
```